# Passing in python arguments as arrays in shell

Tags: shell-script

Running into a situation when writing shell script that executes python script which creates service with the arguments passed. Want to be able to pass in service name and config as arrays as those are the only values that change for creating service, rest of the arguments stay the same.

When running the script below its creating 5 different services (with errors) as each of the argument is used as 1 service call and errors saying other arguments are missing. What am I missing in the script below and is there a better way to approach this requirement? thanks!

StartJobs.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#arguments
service=$1
config=$2
dockerv=$3
action=$4
file=$5

for addr in "$@"; do
 for service in "$@"; do
  for config in "$@"; do
    python /scripts/serviceStart.py -s "$service" -c "$config" -d "$dockerv" -t "$action" "$addr"
   done
 done
done
```

call the script

```
/shellScripts/StartJobs.sh 720Test /720/config.xml 1080Test /1080/config.xml 5.6.0-1 Start 12.70.80.14 

720Test and 1080Test ---service 
/720/config.xml and 1080/config.xml ---config
```

Needs to get single service and single config values each time the /shellScripts/StartJobs.sh runs. Specified above are 2 services and 2 related configs.

Expecting the shell script to execute python script with the arguments and start 2 different services one for 720 and one for 1080 on the same IP.

```
 python /scripts/serviceStart.py -s 720Test -c /720/config.xml -d 5.6.0-1 -t Start 12.70.80.14
 python /scripts/serviceStart.py -s 1080Test -c /1080/config.xml -d 5.6.0-1 -t Start 12.70.80.14
```

Also tried this but does not return any errors nor create a service.

```
#!/bin/bash

args=()
while getopts ':d:t:' opt ; do 
case $opt in 
d) args+=( -d "$OPTARG" ) ;; 
t) args+=( -t "$OPTARG" ) ;;
?) echo "Invalid option $OPTARG" ;;
:) echo "Option $OPTARG needs an argument" ;;
esac
done

myarray[0]= $service
myarray[1]= $config

for ((i=0; i<${#service[@]}; i++) && (j=0; j<${#config[@]}; j++)) ; do
  echo $service
  echo $config
  python /scripts/serviceStart.py -s "${service[i]}" -c "${config[i]}" "${args[@]}" "$ip" 
sleep 5
done
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of the loops. Can you show an example of how you are calling your script and what actual command you would want that call to execute?

Comment: Invocation-------
/shellScripts/StartJobs.sh 720Test /720/config.xml 1080Test /1080/config.xml 5.6.0-1 Start 12.70.80.14

  here 720Test is the service and /720/config.xml is the config(only arguments that need different values each time the command runs)

  Iterate (service and config) as those are the only values that change for the command. Having to start multiple services.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, write how exactly you call the script, and what is the *exact* expected result (exacrly how many iteration of the python script you expect, and what should be the arguments for the python for each iteration). Be precise. Write a list of the python commands that should be resulted by the arguments to your script, with the *exact* arguments that python should receive for each iteration.

Comment: Your addition to your question should be something like: "I call the script as `/shellScripts/StartJobs.sh 720Test /720/config.xml 1080Test /1080/config.xml 5.6.0-1 Start 12.70.80.14`, the result should be: 1. `scripts/serviceStart.py -s 1 -c 2 -d 3 -t 4 5`. 2. `scripts/serviceStart.py -s 6 -c 7 -d 8 -t 9 10` ..."

Comment: @aviro added the call to script and the python script commands that should be executed from the shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> Want to be able to pass in service name and config as arrays

But that's not possible, an executed program gets a single list/array as its command-line arguments, so one way or another, you're going to have to put all the data in that one list.

---

In your example, it looks like you have interleaved the different kinds of fields, and you want

```
StartJobs.sh 720Test /720/config.xml 1080Test /1080/config.xml 5.6.0-1 Start 12.70.80.14
```

to produce the commands

```
python serviceStart.py -s 720Test -c /720/config.xml -d 5.6.0-1 -t Start 12.70.80.14
python serviceStart.py -s 1080Test -c /1080/config.xml -d 5.6.0-1 -t Start 12.70.80.14
```

i.e. the rule seems to be that the last three args in the list are used on each Python invocation (for `-d`, `-t` and the non-option arg at the end), and the rest of the list is used two args at a time (for `-s` and `-c`).

Now, IMO, handling N *last* args specially sounds really uncommon (and awkward to do in the shell, you can only shift items off the start of the list, you can't pop the last ones out), so I'd suggest having the static ones at the start of the list, or better yet, use `getopts` for them. So:

```
#/bin/bash
while getopts ':d:t:a:' opt ; do 
case $opt in 
d) dockerv="$OPTARG" ;; 
t) action="$OPTARG" ;;
a) addr="$OPTARG" ;;
?) echo "Invalid option $OPTARG" ;;
:) echo "Option $OPTARG needs an argument" ;;
esac
done

shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"

if (( $# % 2 == 1 )); then
    echo >&2 "error: got odd number of args"
    exit 1
fi

while [[ "$#" -gt 1 ]]; do
    echo serviceStart.py -s "$1" -c "$2" -d "$dockerv" -t "$action" "$addr"
    shift 2 
done
```

and then

```
% bash startjobs.sh -d 5.6.0-1 -t Start -a 12.70.80.14 -- 720Test /720/config.xml 1080Test /1080/config.xml
serviceStart.py -s 720Test -c /720/config.xml -d 5.6.0-1 -t Start 12.70.80.14
serviceStart.py -s 1080Test -c /1080/config.xml -d 5.6.0-1 -t Start 12.70.80.14
```

<sub>(I'm still not exactly sure if putting different kinds of values in the list of args is the best thing to do, or if it would feel better to individual args with a separator like `1080Test:/1080/config.xml`, or just read the names and paths from stdin. But that's probably bikeshedding, and the easiest implementation might also depend on the format the actual source data is in, so you do what feels best.)</sub>